# A view that shows the name of the server, the id of the instance and the number of active sessions (a session is active if the end timestamp is null)

Tags: postgresql, join, count, where-clause, sql-view

```
CREATE TABLE instances(
    ser_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    id INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    ser_ip VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    creation_ts TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT instance_id PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE characters(
    nickname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    c_level INTEGER NOT NULL,
    game_data VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    start_ts TIMESTAMP ,
    end_ts TIMESTAMP NULL ,
    player_ip VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    instance_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    player_username VARCHAR(15),
    CONSTRAINT chara_nick PRIMARY KEY(nickname)
); 
ALTER TABLE
     instances ADD CONSTRAINT ins_ser_name FOREIGN KEY(ser_name) REFERENCES servers(name);
ALTER TABLE
    instances ADD CONSTRAINT ins_ser_ip FOREIGN KEY(ser_ip) REFERENCES servers(ip);
ALTER TABLE
    characters ADD CONSTRAINT chara_inst_id FOREIGN KEY(instance_id) REFERENCES instances(id);
ALTER TABLE
    characters ADD CONSTRAINT chara_player_username FOREIGN KEY(player_username) REFERENCES players(username);

insert into instances values
('serverA','1','138.201.233.18','active','2020-10-20'),
('serverB','2','138.201.233.19','active','2020-10-20'),
('serverE','3','138.201.233.14','active','2020-10-20');

insert into characters values
('characterA','typeA','1','Game data of characterA','2020-07-18 02:12:12','2020-07-18 02:32:30','192.188.11.1','1','nabin123'),
('characterB','typeB','3','Game data of characterB','2020-07-19 02:10:12',null,'192.180.12.1','2','rabin123'),
('characterC','typeC','1','Game data of characterC','2020-07-18 02:12:12',null,'192.189.10.1','3','sabin123'),
('characterD','typeA','1','Game data of characterD','2020-07-18 02:12:12','2020-07-18 02:32:30','192.178.11.1','2','nabin123'),
('characterE','typeB','3','Game data of characterE','2020-07-19 02:10:12',null,'192.190.12.1','1','rabin123'),
('characterF','typeC','1','Game data of characterF','2020-07-18 02:12:12',null,'192.188.10.1','3','sabin123'),
('characterG','typeD','1','Game data of characterG','2020-07-18 02:12:12',null,'192.188.13.1','1','nabin123'),
('characterH','typeD','3','Game data of characterH','2020-07-19 02:10:12',null,'192.180.17.1','2','bipin123'),
('characterI','typeD','1','Game data of characterI','2020-07-18 02:12:12','2020-07-18 02:32:30','192.189.18.1','3','dhiraj123'),
('characterJ','typeD','3','Game data of characterJ','2020-07-18 02:12:12',null,'192.178.19.1','2','prabin123'),
('characterK','typeB','4','Game data of characterK','2020-07-19 02:10:12','2020-07-19 02:11:30','192.190.20.1','1','rabin123'),
('characterL','typeC','2','Game data of characterL','2020-07-18 02:12:12',null,'192.192.11.1','3','sabin123'),
('characterM','typeC','3','Game data of characterM','2020-07-18 02:12:12',null,'192.192.11.1','2','sabin123');
```

here I need a view that shows the name of the server, the id of the instance and the number of active sessions (a session is active if the end timestamp is null). do my code wrong or something else? i am starting to learn so hoping for positive best answers.

my view

```
create view active_sessions as
select i.ser_name, i.id, count(end_ts) as active
from instances i, characters c
where i.id=c.instance_id and c.end_ts = null
group by i.ser_name, i.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not do what you want:

```
where i.id = c.instance_id and c.end_ts = null
```

Nothing is equal to `null`. You need `is null` to check a value against `null`.

Also, `count(end_ts)` will always produce `0`, as we know already that `end_ts` is `null`, which `count()` does not consider.

Finally, I would highly recommend using a standard join (with the `on` keyword), rather than an implicit join (with a comma in the `from` clause): this old syntax from decades ago should not be used in new code. I think that a `left join` is closer to what you want (it would also take in account instances that have no character at all).

So:

```
create view active_sessions as
select i.ser_name, i.id, count(c.nickname) as active
from instances i
left join characters c on i.id = c.instance_id and c.end_ts is null
group by i.ser_name, i.id;
```